# AngularJS problemas com roteamento de views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route, angular-routes

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web com AngularJS 1.6, e estou me deparando com um erro somente quando abro o index.html direto da pagina. Porém, quando executado direto da IDE funciona normalmente.
Segue print do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo da index.html:

```
<body ng-app="codeAmApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
        <a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="#!categoria"> + Categoria </a>
        <a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="#!tarefa"> + Tarefa </a></button>
        <a ng-click="mostrar = !mostrar" ng-show="mostrar" class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="#!listaPorCategoria"> Lista de tarefas por categoria </a></button>
        <a ng-click="mostrar = !mostrar" ng-hide="mostrar" class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="#/!"> Lista de tarefas </a></button>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Código do AngularJS:

```
var codeAmApp = angular.module('codeAmApp', ["ngRoute"]);

codeAmApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "porTarefa.html"
        })
        .when("/categoria", {
            templateUrl : "categoria.html"
        })
        .when("/tarefa", {
            templateUrl : "tarefa.html"
        })
        .when("/listaPorCategoria", {
            templateUrl : "porCategoria.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso é devido simplesmente ao fato de você estar abrindo o arquivo diretamente.

O AngularJS requer um servidor HTTP (na verdade, as tecnologias da Google, inclusive o próprio Chrome, requerem isso. Eu tentei executar JQuery abrindo o arquivo HTML diretamente no Chrome e deu o mesmo erro. Não lembro a versão do Google Chrome nem do JQuery), como Apache ou IIS.

Algumas IDEs têm um servidor Web embutido (built-in), como é o caso do Brackets, que eu uso no Ubuntu 16.04, e certamente deve ser o caso da sua IDE.

Para resolver esse problema você terá que configurar seu servidor Web e acessar do localhost.